# C stroull equivalent in Java

Tags: java, objective-c, c, long-integer

I have a Objective C code,which I have to translate in Java,but I have a little problem with converting one line. In Objective C code I have : `UInt64 iz = strtoull(s,&s1,16);`. I was searching over the internet abotu strtoull and I find this information for it :

> strtoul will convert a string to an unsigned long integer. An
>   important feature of this function is the ability to accept data in
>   various number bases and convert to decimal.
>
> The first argument must not contain a + or -. The second argument
>   (char **endptr) seems to be a waste of space! If it is set to NULL,
>   STRTOL seems to work its way down the string until it finds an invalid
>   character and then stops. All valid chars read are then converted if
>   the string starts with an invalid character the function returns ZERO
>   (0).
>
> The Third argument (base) can have a value of 0 or 2-32.
>
> 0 - strtol will attempt to pick the base. Only Dec, Oct Hex supported.
>   2-31 - The base to use.

I tried to find a way to do this in Java.As a made some researches I got this :

```
long l=Long.parseLong(md5Hash, 16);
```

And my question is,is parseLong equivalent to strtoull and can I use it for my application? If not can you suggest me what can I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't parse an MD5 into a Java long.  MD5 is 128 bits.

Comment: Array of bytes.  Parse each group of two hex characters as a byte and put into a 16 byte array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because `long` is *signed* in Java. If you need unsigned integers for the full value range of 64 Bit then you have to use the `BigInteger` class.

Comment: (So strtoull(s,&s1,16) becomes new BigInteger(String))

Answer (score 1):

`Long.parseLong` is the usual way of parsing a string into a long. But be aware that Java does not have unsigned types.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent but keep in mind that `long` in Java is not unsigned. Therefore, a Java `long` is in `[-2^63, 2^63 - 1]`.

Comment: I know that, I just want to be sure that this is the way to do it! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

use
    BigInteger(String val, int radix)